# PyQt 5 text erased in TreeView when clicked

Tags: pyqt5, qtreeview

I am writing an userinterface using PyQt. One component is a TreeView which is editable. However when clicking on one cell to edit it the whole text disappears. So if one clicks somewhere else the text will be still erased. 
What I want to have is a behavior similar to Excel where the content of a cell becomes a blue background and can be edited. 
I am pretty sure it is only about setting a flag or so but can't come up with any solution so far.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example of the tree? In a regular `QTreeWidget`, the text doesn't disappears, it is just selected.

Comment: Sure. The first screenshot is after start-up, and the second after double-clicking the field. http://abload.de/img/one8nbjk.png and 
http://abload.de/img/twovcsrx.png 
What I want is that the text doesn't appear but is selected as in Excel for instance.
The code for the view is generated by pyuic5, and for the TreeView it outputs 
self.treeView = QtWidgets.QTreeView(self.centralwidget)
        self.treeView.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 10, 1451, 551))
        self.treeView.setSortingEnabled(True)
        self.treeView.setObjectName("treeView")